# Use of if/else in Dataframe.assign() results in ValueError: The truth value of a Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a ton of data transforms defined in a batch transform language that supports this structure: x = iif(condition, a, b). I want to rewrite these using dataframes.

I'm using Dataframe.assign() but get ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame(['apple', 'orange', 'granite'], columns=['name'])
    df.assign(taste = lambda x: 'rocky' if (x.name=='granite') else 'yummy')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-e9ad71ccc45b> in <module>()
----> 1 df.assign(taste = lambda x: 'rocky' if (x.name=='granite') else 'yummy')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in assign(self, **kwargs)
   3305         if PY36:
   3306             for k, v in kwargs.items():
-> 3307                 data[k] = com._apply_if_callable(v, data)
   3308         else:
   3309             # <= 3.5: do all calculations first...

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py in _apply_if_callable(maybe_callable, obj, **kwargs)
    403 
    404     if callable(maybe_callable):
--> 405         return maybe_callable(obj, **kwargs)
    406 
    407     return maybe_callable

<ipython-input-39-e9ad71ccc45b> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df.assign(taste = lambda x: 'rocky' if (x.name=='granite') else 'yummy')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1571         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1572                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1573                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1574 
   1575     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

At first I thought this was due to a limitation of the keywords allowed in assign(), but a very similar construct works with apply():

```
df['name'].apply(lambda x: 'rocky' if (x=='granite') else 'yummy')

0    yummy
1    yummy
2    rocky
Name: name, dtype: object
```

However, this doesn't allow me use to an if-condition that uses multiple columns from the dataframe. Is there a way to get assign() to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling `Series.apply`, the lambda receives each row value (i.e., a scalar value). With `assign`, the lambda receives the entire DataFrame. Understanding this means you can now do something such as

```
df.assign(taste=lambda x: np.where(x['name'] == 'granite', 'r', 'y'))

      name taste
0    apple     y
1   orange     y
2  granite     r
```

Or,

```
df.assign(taste=np.where(df['name'] == 'granite', 'r', 'y'))
      name taste
0    apple     y
1   orange     y
2  granite     r
```

Or, more simply, for in-place assignment,

```
df['taste'] = np.where(df['name'] == 'granite', 'r', 'y')
df

      name taste
0    apple     y
1   orange     y
2  granite     r
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the answer and the explanation of why apply() worked in the initial formulation.

Answer (score 2):

assign is not the function you should using with condition assignment

```
df['taste']=np.where(df['name'].eq('granite'),'rocky','yummy')
df
Out[513]: 
      name  taste
0    apple  yummy
1   orange  yummy
2  granite  rocky
```

Comment: Thanks! The important point is to use np.where() in place of if/else. The answer below shows that assign() can be used too.